# Point top level domain to Openshift app with CNAME? (ip problems)

Tags: dns, ip, openshift, cname, domain-name

In Openshift you need to point (as it's recommended on Openshift) your domain to their CNAME records, like that:

```
mysite.com => cname: app-mynick.rhcloud.com
```

But according to DNS rules (as my domain registrator says) CNAME pointing applicable only for subdomains like this:

```
subdomain.mysite.com
```

So, how should I behave in this situation with my top level domain?

The problem is Openshift gives my app dynamic IP, so, somewhen it may be changed and my website wouldn't be accessible...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved the issue with CloudFlare CNAME Flattening.

Here is article - https://blog.cloudflare.com/introducing-cname-flattening-rfc-compliant-cnames-at-a-domains-root/ - that describes why you can't point root domain to CNAME record in your DNS, and how CNAME Flattening can solve my problem.

So now, I can "point top level (root) domain to Openshift app with CNAME".